# Issue while upload/send file with post request using Jmeter

Tags: json, rest, jmeter

I have one post request where I am uploading image as per below using postman :

[image]

I am trying to perform same request using Jmeter. I did following setting in Jmeter :

[image]

But somehow it is not working. I tried with multipart/form-data for POST option also but no luck.

our API developer has set validation that if api get any other file then image then they send response : `invalid file type`. I am getting this response all time when do POST request with image from Jmeter. It works fine with postman.

In Debugger post processor it shows like this : `HTTPsampler.Files=path:'C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\samplex.png'|param:'fileName'|mimetype:'image/png'`

Comment: Did you tried with JMeter 5? Did you tried to use JMeter HTTPS recording to record postman request?

Comment: Also try removing `file` from Parameter Name column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve issue by removing `Parameter name` and `MIME Type` from tab `File Upload`. I did provide only file path and it works. Also I unchecked `Use multipart/form-data for POST`

Answer (score 0):

You see button Browse.. in picture 2 you post. Do for same with Postman, choose file and send the request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a valid file at the specified path.
2. Check your postman whether it is sending any other things in the header like `Content-Type`.
3. Check out [File Uploads using JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/08/file-upload-with-jmeter/) guide for more information on simulating file uploads with JMeter

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment, If you want to send binary file as is (not as parameter value), remove the `Parameter Name` column value (file)

See JMeter's [HTTP Request reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for more details:

> **File Path:** Name of the file to send. If left blank, JMeter does not send a file, if filled in, JMeter **automatically sends the request as a multipart form request**.
>   If it is a POST or PUT or PATCH request and there is a single file whose **'Parameter name' attribute (below) is omitted, then the file is sent as the entire body of the request**, i.e. no wrappers are added. This allows arbitrary bodies to be sent. This functionality is present for POST requests, and also for PUT requests.